# iOS how to split static cell into two sections

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitextfield

I am very new to both Objective-C and iOS development and I am trying to build a form in my app. I want to be able to split static cells into two sections as shown in this screenshot:

[image: static cell split into two sections]

This is exactly what I am trying achieve, two static cells with 2 sections in each, each section containing a UITextField. What is the best way to do this?

Any help / advice is very much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just create a `UIView`, and round the corners of the layer. Add the `UITextFields` onto the `UIView`, and draw the separators onto the `UIView`.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you just drag out 4 UILabels in the areas you require.

Create a background image which has the grid / colours you desire.

Comment: Hey thanks for your advice. I did try this, but the top of the vertical lines get cut off by the border of the static cell. Screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/vFA3Amu.png